# How to pass the value to a user-defined function in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to pass the value of `employee_name` that I get from XML to a user-defined function in XSL. Please see the code below:

```
<xsl:for-each select="employees/employee">
  <xsl:value-of select="employee_name"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="
    my:compareCI(
      '--how to pass employee_name Value--',
      '--how to pass employee_name Value--'
    )
  " />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Please any help me as I am new to XSL.

Comment: I assume you mean XSL or XSLT. title is mispelled

Comment: Note that this is only possible in XSLT2.0 and that some systems still only support XSLT1.0

Answer (score 5):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com">


    <xsl:function name="ns1:functionName">
        <xsl:param name="employee_name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$employee_name"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="ns1:functionName('John Doe')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```